# Is there a way for buttons to display multiple texts?

Tags: javascript

I have this idea where if you press a button, it'll display a text, but not only one text, but multiple, just not at once. If you press the button again, it'll display another text after it. So far, I'm only limited to only one text being displayed. I'm not really sure how to go from what I'm trying to achieve. I had an idea about using arrays but arrays and buttons didn't seem to work all that great, at least for me. I might have done something wrong for it to not work. Anyways, the idea was that the button would call from the array each time you'd click it so it'd display a different text. 
So if you press the button once, it would output: "Hello"
And if you press it again, it would output: "How are you?"

and so on and so forth.

How would I do this in terms of making something like this happen?

Disclaimer: I don't want the text to be replaced with a new text. I want it solely outputted afterwards.

```
  <button id = "age-button" button onClick = "ageButton()">AGE!</button>

<script>

    function ageButton() {

 var text = "You are born.";
 document.getElementById("age1").innerHTML = text;


}

</script>
```

This code above only displays one text. How would I let it display another text after I press the button again?

Comment: Can you show us some HTML and/or JavaScript to explain what you're talking about? This sounds like a `click` handler that changes the button's label.

Comment: Of course. Lemme quickly add it.

Comment: Hint: What is the `id` of that element? It's not `age1`.

Comment: @tadman sorry my bad, I forgot to include the <p id = "age1"></p> bit of code. That age1 id is where I'd want the first line of code to be displayed after pressing the button once.

Comment: Well if you're changing the label of the button you want to manipulate that element, not some other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do that.

```js
let texts = ["You are born", "Hi there", "I'm ready"];

function ageButton() {
  let line = texts.shift(); //use shift to get the first element in array
  if (line) {
    //use += operator to append to previous content
    document.getElementById("age1").innerHTML += "<p>" + line + "</p>";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="age-button" onclick="ageButton()">AGE!</button>
<div id="age1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Define array of string that you would like to show on each click

const labels = [
  "String 1",
  "String 2",
  "String 3"
  // ... so on (add as many as you like)
];

// lets start from zero index
let currentIndex = 0;

// get the button HTMLElement
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("#next-btn");
const contentsEl = document.querySelector("#contents");

// attach onClick event handler / listner
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // get the label string to show
  const label = labels[currentIndex];
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = label;

  contentsEl.append(p);

  // increment the index
  currentIndex++;
  
  // set a trap
  if (currentIndex === labels.length) {
      //(bonus) disable the button when you reach the end
      this.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="next-btn">Show Next</button>
<div id="contents"></div>
```